# DataGridView stops displaying after changing the form controls

Tags: datagridview, datatable

I created a fairly simple form; it opens an Excel file, and populates a data table based on the contents of that spreadsheet.  Finished version 1, tested, debugged - and it works fine.  Once the Load functionality completes, the datagridview on my form displays the data.

Version 2 needed a "Validate" button, with logic behind it, so I added that, tested, debugged ... and noticed that the data wasn't appearing in the datagridview any more.  I couldn't see anything I'd done to change the Load logic, nor the table definition, etc.

So, I reverted to the saved copy of version 1 (why, yes, I have done this before - heh!); it still works as it did before, displaying the data at the end of the Load.

As soon as I add any control to the form, the data no longer displays.  Interestingly, I also get a bunch of warnings, in Form1.Designer.cs: The field 'CSVScanApp.Form1.FileName' is never used
That repeats for, interestingly/coincidentally, each of the columns in the data table.

I know you'll want to see the code, so here goes:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cxApp = new cExcel.Application();
            dsScanRows = new DataSet();
            dtScanTable = dsScanRows.Tables.Add();
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("LeaseNo", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("DocDate", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("Function", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("DocType", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("Integration", typeof(string));
            dtScanTable.Columns.Add("ScanDate", typeof(string));
            // Category "codes" and their corresponding full names
            CtgyDict.Add("DataSheet", "Data Sheet");
            CtgyDict.Add("Surface", "Surface/ROW/Pipeline Agreements");
            CtgyDict.Add("TitleReport", "Title Report");
            CtgyDict.Add("MapPlats", "Map & Plats");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error(s) encountered:" + crlf + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

And the logic from the Load button, that actually parses the Excel into the data table:

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cxWB = cxApp.Workbooks.Open(tbSourceFile.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                cExcel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false, 0, false, 1, 0); // open Read-Only
            cExcel.Sheets cxSheets = cxWB.Worksheets;
            cExcel._Worksheet cxSheet = (cExcel._Worksheet)cxSheets.get_Item(1); // Sheet 1
            cExcel.Range cxRange = cxSheet.UsedRange;
            int iRowMax = cxRange.Rows.Count;
            int iRow;
            string sFileName, sLease,sDocDate,sCategory,sCtgyName,sDocType;
            Double dblDocDate;
            string sCompany = tbCompany.Text; // specs said "CompanyNN", but were wrong...
            string sScanDate = tbScanDate.Text; // hope it's correctly entered...  :p
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null; // reset from any previous data
            dtScanTable.Clear(); // make sure this starts empty
            // loop through each row in the source
            for (iRow = 2; iRow <= iRowMax; iRow++)
            {
                sFileName = (string)(cxRange.Cells[iRow, iSourceColFileName] as cExcel.Range).Value2;
                if (sFileName == null | sFileName == "")
                { } // ignore blank rows
                else
                {
                    sLease = sFileName.Split('_')[0]; // e.g., 100845.00A_1.pdf --> 100845.00A
                    dblDocDate = Convert.ToDouble((cxRange.Cells[iRow, iSourceColDocDate] as cExcel.Range).Value2);
                    sDocDate = DateTime.FromOADate(dblDocDate).ToShortDateString();
                    //if (sDocDate == "") { sDocDate = sScanDate; } // default to today???
                    sCategory = (string)(cxRange.Cells[iRow, iSourceColCtgy] as cExcel.Range).Value2;
                    try
                    {
                        sCtgyName = CtgyDict[sCategory];
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        sCtgyName = sCategory; // i.e., not in the replacement list
                    }
                    sDocType = (string)(cxRange.Cells[iRow, iSourceColDocType] as cExcel.Range).Value2;
                    dtScanTable.Rows.Add(sFileName,sCompany,sLease,sDocDate,sFunction,sCtgyName,sDocType,sIntegration,sScanDate);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtScanTable;
            btnValidate.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error(s) encountered:" + crlf + ex.Message);
            btnSave.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

And, in the Form1.Designer.cs, these are the lines associated with the warnings that only show up after I add a control to the form:

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn FileName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Company;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn LeaseNo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DocDate;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Function;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Category;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DocType;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Integration;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ScanDate;
```

The new line that corresponds to the new Validate button gets added after that block, if that's relevant.

I'm clearly in way over my head, here; I've done something, somehow, somewhere - but simply can't imagine what, nor how to get past this.  (Fortunately, the original and modified versions both create the output that I need, so it's not urgent - but it drives me nuts that the grid won't show my data!)

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot two lines of code, from the top:           DataSet dsScanRows;
        DataTable dtScanTable;

Comment: Another update; I added a handler for the Form Closing event, and - once again - the data stopped displaying in the grid.  I then compared the FormDesigner.cs from the new and previous versions - and the new no longer had most of the (any of?) the definitions for the data grid columsn; they vanished.  Using Beyond Compare (shameless plug for an amazing tool!), I just copied those lines of code back from the old form design code - and the data appears again.

Comment: So now, the question seems to be - why would that part of the form design code disappear whenever I add a new element to the form?  (Still, "what did I do wrong? how??")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened again - apparently, there's a bug in VS (I'm using 2012 now, but the original occurrence, above, was VS2010).  I don't know if this will manifest only when you define the datagridview properties in code, or if it always happens - but adding another control to my form wiped out a bunch of code from FormDesigner.cs, and you just have to put it back.

So, the solution involves (1) having a backup copy and (2) using a good text comparison tool.